# How to display the number of people who like posts?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code that displays posts added by a user. The post consists of the name, the added time, the content of the post and 4 buttons. The problem is that I want to display the number of people who like and dislike this post next to each buttons. I know I have to create a new function for this, but I don't know how to display it, because posts are displayed using a foreach loop, so if I were to create a new function I would have to give foreach to display, but then it probably wouldn't work. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do it?

```js
    public function colors()
    {
        $id = $_SESSION['id'];
        $like = $this->data['like'];
        $sql = $this->database->connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM user JOIN post ON user.id = post.user_id JOIN post_like ON post.id = post_like.post_id where post.user_id = :user_id and post_id = :post_id group by post.id DESC");
        $sql->bindParam(':user_id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sql->bindParam(':post_id', $like, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sql->execute();

        if ($sql->rowCount()) {
            return "yellow";
        } else
            return "red";
    }
}
```

```
<?php foreach ($tweet->userData as $user) { ?>
    <div class='col-xl-8'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='btn-block d-flex justify-content-between'>
                <div>
                   <?php  echo $user['autor']   ?>
                    </div>
                <div>
                   <?php echo $user['date_to_add'] ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php echo $user['comment'] ?>
        <form action='' method='post'>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-12 col-xl-12 d-flex justify-content-between'>
                    <button class='button2' style="background-color: <?php echo $color ?>" name='dodaj_like'><i class='fas fa-heart'></i><input type='hidden' name='like' value="<?php echo $user['id']?>" />Cool</button>
                    <button class='button2' name='dodaj_dislike'><i class='fas fa-heart-broken'></i><input type='hidden' name='dislike' value="<?php echo $user['id']?>"/>Awful</button>
                    <button class='button2' name='dodaj_comment' ><i class='far fa-comment-dots'></i><input type='hidden' name='comment' value="<?php echo $user['id']?>"/>Comment</button>
                    <button class='button2' name='dodaj_share'><i class='far fa-share-square'></i><input type='hidden' name='share' value="<?php echo $user['id']?>"/>Share</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

```
public function display()
{
    $field5 = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = $this->database->connect()->prepare("SELECT post.id, CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name) AS autor, comment, date_to_add FROM user JOIN post ON user.id = post.user_id where user_id = :user_id group by post.id DESC");
    $sql->bindParam(':user_id',$field5, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->execute();

    if($sql->rowCount())
    {
        $this->userData = [];

        while ($row = $sql->fetch())
        {
            $this->userData[] = $row;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question sounds familiar. Did you post something similar a few days ago?

Comment: Join with the `likes` table in your query to get the like and dislike counts. You shouldn't need another function.

Comment: yes, only that solution made it not display posts.

Comment: Then you must have done it wrong. If you post what you tried, we can help you fix it.

Comment: I have this query `SELECT post.id, CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name) AS autor, comment, date_to_add, count(post_like.post_id) as likes FROM user JOIN post ON user.id = post.user_id JOIN post_like ON post.id = post_like.post_id where post.user_id = 1 group by post.user_id DESC;` but after this query, it doesn't show the new posts added. I can add posts, but only the old posts display.

Comment: It shoiuld be `GROUP BY post.id`. Otherwise you're combining all of the author's posts into one row.

Comment: That's change nothing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should work. Can you post sample data at sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: What I should do at sqlfiddle.com, I don't know this page ?

Comment: In the left side, put all the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO table` statements to create a sample of all the tables needed for the query. You can also automate this by using the "Text to DDL" button and pasting in the text output of the tables.

Comment: that looks like display only posts which have at least 1 like.

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` to include posts with no likes.

Comment: Ok that work, but I yet want to display the number of people who don't like posts from, so how I can join table 'user' and 'table' post_dislike '?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN (SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) AS dislike_count FROM post_dislike GROUP BY post_id) AS post_dislike ON post.id = post_dislike.post_id`

Comment: easiest way is `SELECT post.id, CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name) AS autor, comment, date_to_add, (select count(*)  from post_like WHERE post_like.post_id=post.id) as likes, (select count(*) from post_dislike WHERE post_dislike.post_id=post.id) as dislikes FROM user JOIN post ON user.id = post.user_id where post.user_id = 1`

Comment: @Barmar if you left join both you need to count distinct like and dislike ids or user ids or something; otherwise 2 likes and 3 dislikes will report as 6 of both

Comment: @ysth That's why I joined with a subquery, not the table directly.

Comment: @Barmar ah, right

Comment: Ok, now that works, I really thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

Join with subqueries that get the like and dislike counts.

```
SELECT post.id, CONCAT(first_name,' ', last_name) AS autor, comment, date_to_add, IFNULL(like_count, 0) AS like_count, IFNULL(dislike_count, 0) AS dislike_count
FROM user 
JOIN post ON user.id = post.user_id 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) AS like_count
    FROM post_like
    GROUP BY post_id
) AS l ON l.post_id on post.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) AS dislike_count
    FROM post_dislike
    GROUP BY post_id
) AS d ON d.post_id on post.id
where user_id = :user_id group by post.id DESC
```

Comment: I want also change color button, If user like post, button should be yellow, and if user don't yet like post, button should be red. Now every button is red. I put my code in main post.

Comment: I'm not going to write your whole application for you, sorry.

Comment: Which user likes/dislikes the post? The only `user_id` you have in the query is the author of the posts.